# Mechanize browser and soup - Differents results with same code

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

i'm using mechanize browser and soup to recover some informations.
username and password are in my csv file.
When i test my script whit only the account1 in the csv file, it works. I have all the html code i want.
Now, when i overwrite account1 by account2 in the csv file, there is no the html code i want. The data are now in javascript tag.

My code :

```
br2.open("URL")
res2 = br2.open("URL")
html2 = res2.read()
print html2
```

And html code i want is in this script

```
<script>
var cacheKillerVersion = "131203105521";
function launch() {
    // quit if this function has already been called
    if (arguments.callee.done) {return;}

    // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
    arguments.callee.done = true;

    // kill the timer
    if (_timer) {
        clearInterval(_timer);
        _timer = null;
    }

    var prodMode = true;
    var debugLevel = "";
    var debugLogTarget = "";
    window.DBG = new AjxDebug({level:AjxDebug.NONE, target:debugLogTarget});
    // figure out the debug level
    if (debugLevel == 't') {
        DBG.showTiming(true);
    } else if (debugLevel) {
        DBG.setDebugLevel(debugLevel);
    }

    AjxHistoryMgr.BLANK_FILE = "/public/blankHistory.html";
    var noSplashScreen = "";
    var protocolMode = "http";


    var batchInfoResponse = ALL THE HTML CODE I WANT TO SCRAP
```

How could be possible ?

Comment: what is `account1`, `account2` ? if they have different values then it can work different . Did you check those "accounts" using browser ?

Comment: use print do display what you  have in variables when you run it - maybe you have different values then you expect. Maybe you have to `strip()` spaces or "\n", or you have to do something more with your data.

Comment: Account1 and account2 are only login.

Comment: as I said: first use `print()` to check values in variables - it is called "print debugging" - and check if there is not space or `"\n"` at the end. You don't see space, tab or `"\n"` but for code it can make problem.

Comment: Hi, i found what is the problem. Sometimes, website use ajaxversion, sometimes html version. I'll try to force html version. Thanks for ur advices